# Wilcoxon Signed-Rank with unequal samples

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

My apologies if this is a novice question:

I am using a 2 tailed Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test to determine if suspension days decrease following a year of PBIS implementation in a middle school.
Sample: 
2017-2018 Year 1 (pre-PBIS) 7th graders – 210 students
2018-2019 Year 2 (post-PBIS) 7th graders – 203 students

I am not following the same students, rather I am collecting data for the same grade across 2 years.

How do I account for the unequal sample sizes?  i.e. How do I use matched pairs with one group having 210 students and the other having 203 students?  Should I randomly chose 203 students from the larger sample so that each group has the same number of data points?

Comment: You should not discard data. The test is fine with unequal samples.

Comment: To me, this looks like an unpaired situation. In this sense, Wilcoxon's *rank-sum* test would be more appropriate (and also solves your technical problem).

Comment: Thank you both so much for the guidance